# ProbeEndpointsStrategy: Duplicate endpoints for id 'httptrace' detected. Omitting (same with 'threaddump')

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Small question regarding SpringBoot Admin and a rather strange log I do not know how to fix.

My current setup is:
SpringBoot Admin Server 2.3.1
SpringBoot 2.4.0 (with actuator)
Spring Cloud Ilford (with Spring Cloud Kubernetes)

On a very simple SBA app:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

I am getting the following when deployed on Kubernetes (tried Minikube, eks, gks, all have this issue).
However, it is not reproducible running on localhost.

```
2020-11-xx WARN [,,,] 47 --- [or-http-epoll-1] d.c.b.a.s.s.e.ProbeEndpointsStrategy     : Duplicate endpoints for id 'httptrace' detected. Omitting: [ProbeEndpointsStrategy.DetectedEndpoint(definition=ProbeEndpointsStrategy.EndpointDefinition(id=httptrace, path=httptrace), endpoint=Endpoint(id=httptrace, url=http://{some wrong ip here}:8000/actuator/httptrace))]
2020-11-xx  WARN [,,,] 47 --- [or-http-epoll-1] d.c.b.a.s.s.e.ProbeEndpointsStrategy     : Duplicate endpoints for id 'threaddump' detected. Omitting: [ProbeEndpointsStrategy.DetectedEndpoint(definition=ProbeEndpointsStrategy.EndpointDefinition(id=threaddump, path=threaddump), endpoint=Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://{some wrong ip here}:8000/actuator/threaddump))]
```

The issue:

- the IPs are incorrect
- the port is an incorrect port, there is nothing on port 8000
- my httptrace and threaddump are not under actuator/xxx

My actuator endpoints are all under /

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

May I ask what is the root cause of this, or is there any property needed to be configured in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the latest Spring Boot 2.5.2 and Spring Boot admin 2.5.2